# Taylor Polynomial for $1/x$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm doing a problem that guides you through proving that the Taylor expansion for $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ converges for all $x$ such that $0<x<2$.

I have shown that $$f(x) - p_n(x)= \frac{(1-x)^{n+1}}{x} $$ for $0<x<2$, where $p_n(x)$ is the nth Taylor polynomial centered at $x=1$.

So to show the claim, is it enough that for all x such that $0<x<2$, we have $|1-x|<1$, so that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} [f(x) - p_n(x)] = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(1-x)^{n+1}}{x}=\frac{1}{x}\lim_{n \to \infty}c^{n+1}=0?$$ where $c =|1-x|<1$?

Comment: Looks good to me